# SQL List the percentage of names starting with A, B, C - Z from a column

Tags: sql, sql-server, count, substring, sql-like

I want to show the percentage of each alphabet of a name from a column.

ex. A = 20%, B = 30%, Z = 10% etc.

Names:

```
Apple
Ace
Benedict
Been
Broom
Car
Make
Safe
Thanksgiving
Zappers
```

Answer (score 0):

You need [`LEFT()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/left-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) and [`COUNT()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/count-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) and `GROUP BY` to get the expected result:

Please find the sample execution:

```
CREATE TABLE TestTable (String VARCHAR (100));

INSERT INTO TestTable (String) VALUES
('Apple'),
('Ace'),
('Benedict'),
('Been'),
('Broom'),
('Car'),
('Make'),
('Safe'),
('Thanksgiving'),
('Zappers');

DECLARE @TCount AS INT = 0;
SELECT @TCount = COUNT(*) FROM TestTable;

SELECT LEFT(String, 1) AS FChar, 
       CONCAT(COUNT(LEFT(String, 1)) *100 / @TCount, '%') AS CharPercent
FROM TestTable 
GROUP BY LEFT(String, 1)
ORDER BY LEFT(String, 1)
```

[**Working demo on db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=f1637ebd3f5796ed764fa4c0fddf7211)

Answer (score 0):

You can use window functions.  The correct logic is:

```
SELECT LEFT(name, 1) AS first_char,
       COUNT(*) * 100.0 / SUM(COUNT(*)) OVER() AS pct
FROM t
GROUP BY LEFT(name, 1)
ORDER BY first_char;
```